# Android: implementing basic encryption into email application

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm currently building an email application and as part of it i need to implement some basic email encryption just to ensure they are securely sent and received any help is appreciated as I've not got much knowledge when it comes to android or java encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these functions:

```
 private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
 private static final byte[] keyValue =
        new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'I', 's', 'A', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };


 public String encrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
    // String encryptedValue = new Base64.encoder();

    return Base64.encodeToString(encValue, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public String decrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    //byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decode(encryptedValue, Base64.DEFAULT);

    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

Comment: thanks Federico, would i have this in a separate java file when calling it?

Comment: ok thanks, if you have the time could you explain how this works just so i'm not blindly using something i don't understand.